# cant open html page in dialog

Tags: jquery, html, dialog

I created a html page and i want to open the html page in a dialog onclick.

Html:

```
  <div id="oncloseTemp">
    ---
    ---
  </div>


   <li class="closebutton"><a href="#" class="bt btright" >close</a></li>
```

If i click the close, then i want to get the oncloseTemp div in dialog. I tried but i am getting the html page in the same page below my web page.

```
    $('.closebutton').live('click', function(event){
    $("#oncloseTemp").dialog('open');
    return false;
    });
```

can anyone help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

To show a div as popup, better you can use jQuery dialogue.

Use the below script to open a div as popup using jQuery with your given HTML mark-up. Please dont forget to reffer the jQuery & JQuery UI script files. Please see the below URL for a demo and more details.

http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

```
    <script>  
    $(function() { 
        $( "#oncloseTemp" ).dialog({      
        autoOpen: false,      
        height: 300,
        width: 350,
        modal: true
        });
        $('.closebutton').live('click', function(event){
        $("#oncloseTemp").dialog('open');
        });
    });  
    </script>

   <div id="oncloseTemp">
    ---
    ---
   </div>

   <li class="closebutton"><a href="#" class="bt btright" >close</a></li>
```

Comment: its displaying on my page..i dont get it onclicking the button :-/

Comment: make your click event like this 
 `$('.closebutton').click(function(event) {`
 `});`

Comment: @anuRadha have you added the refferences to jQuery & jQuery UI ?

Comment: yeah i did ..if i click the close nothing is happening :-/

Comment: @anuRadha I have editted the script in my answer. Please try that